# CS1702 Runtime error with Kendo.Mvc and System.Web.Mvc 4.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, assembly-binding-redirect

We are having an issue trying to get Kendo.Mvc to bind to version 4.0.0.1 of System.Web.Mvc

The Kendo.Mvc version is

```
Kendo.Mvc, Version=2013.3.1324.440, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4
```

This assembly references version 4.0.0.0 of System.Web.Mvc

We've added a binding redirect to our Web.Config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The solution builds just fine, but at run time we get this...

```
CS1702: Warning as Error: Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime policy
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: No, the best advise that I got was that it was a valid warning. To allow the build to proceed I ended up adding a compilerOptions="/nowarn:1702" to the compiler tag in the web config

Comment: I added the "/nowarn:1702" to compilerOptions but still get the error at runtime... any ideas?

Comment: @Ricardo no, sorry. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/10565300.aspx?PageIndex=2. It suggests updating the MVC4 package will help resolve that warning (remove -whatif to actually update)

```
Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.40804.0 -whatif
```

Comment: I'd give you two if I could.

Comment: It's okay one day the OP might accept this answer :-)